# Regex for positive or negative integer only with no look arounds

Tags: regex

I would like to match integers only. No decimals and no leading 0s. Look arounds are not allowed. The best solution I had was `^\d+$` but it matches `0001` on https://regex101.com/.

Here are some test cases

```
1 
-1 
+1 
A1
)1 
0.1 
0001
1,000
1.1
0
```

This is what the result must be

```
1 #true
-1 #true
+1 #true
A1 #false
)1 #false
0.1 #false
0001 #false
1,000 #false
1.1 #false
0 #true
```

### Edit

I also added the condition to match `0`.

Comment: Use `^[+-]?[1-9]\d*$` or `^[+-]?[1-9][0-9]*$`

Comment: _Look arounds are not allowed_ could you please explain why ?

Comment: The regex library I am using in Rust says, 'lookarounds not allowed'. @Nicolas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```js
^([+-]?[1-9][0-9]*|0)$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kJOfpf/2) and the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(%5B%2B-%5D%3F%5B1-9%5D%5B0-9%5D*%7C0)%24):

[image]

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(` - start of a group:

  - `[+-]?` - a `-` or `+`, optional
  - `[1-9]` -  a digit from `1` to `9`
  - `[0-9]*` - any zero or more digits
- `|` - or

  - `0` - a zero
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: I just added the condition to match 0.

Comment: Did you mean ^[+-]?[1-9]\d*|^0$ as opposed to ^[+-]?[1-9]\d*|0$

Comment: @Alex Please see what I posted: **`^([+-]?[1-9][0-9]*|0)$`**